# remove duplicate or repeated order number from subtitle

Tags: c#

I want to remove duplicate or repeated order number from subtitle. but I'm still confused about how to remove it.

Here is the original sample:

```
1
1

00:00:00,000  -->  00:00:03,160
[music]
2

2

00:00:03,160  -->  00:00:06,620
Thank you for joining me in Arduino step by step 2017,
3

3

00:00:06,620  -->  00:00:10,900
getting started, in this lecture I will describe
4

4

00:00:10,900  -->  00:00:15,640
the course so that you know exactly what to expect from it.
5

5

00:00:15,640  -->  00:00:20,060
Firstly, you may be wondering if this course is right for you
```

Desired output:

```
1
00:00:00,000  -->  00:00:03,160
[music]

2
00:00:03,160  -->  00:00:06,620
Thank you for joining me in Arduino step by step 2017,

3
00:00:06,620  -->  00:00:10,900
getting started, in this lecture I will describe

4
00:00:10,900  -->  00:00:15,640
the course so that you know exactly what to expect from it.

5
00:00:15,640  -->  00:00:20,060
Firstly, you may be wondering if this course is right for you,
```

What i have tried:

```
String file = @"nameoffile.srt";
string lines = File.ReadAllText(file);
string[] people = lines.Split(new string[] { "\r\n\r\n" },
                           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var item in people)
{
     Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

How can I remove the duplicate repeated number from the subtitle.

Comment: Tip: `HashSet<String>`.

Comment: I'd go a step further and say HashSet<int>. Because there might be a duplicate sentence somewhere in the script, and it might not be the goal to remove it.

Comment: @Sidewinder94 , i just want to remove duplicate order number from that text, canyou give me solution

Comment: Where do you get the input from? Is it possible to correct its creation?

Comment: can this file also contain duplicates that are on purpose and should not be removed?

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest to use [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netcore-3.1), filter out the empty lines and then run the [Distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netcore-3.1) method at the end

```
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(file).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).Distinct();

foreach (var item in allLines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output:

> 1
> 00:00:00,000  -->  00:00:03,160
> [music]
> 2
> 00:00:03,160  -->  00:00:06,620
> Thank you for joining me in Arduino step by step 2017,
> 3
> 00:00:06,620  -->  00:00:10,900
> getting started, in this lecture I will describe
> 4
> 00:00:10,900  -->  00:00:15,640
> the course so that you know exactly what to expect from it.
> 5
> 00:00:15,640  -->  00:00:20,060
> Firstly, you may be wondering if this course is right for you

I would advise to treat this parsing in a more object oriented manner. Create a class as a representation of this input. By overriding the `ToString` method you can specify how the information is supposed to be displayed

```
public class Item
{
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string TimeStampString { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{OrderNumber}{Environment.NewLine}" +
               $"{TimeStampString}{Environment.NewLine}" +
                $"{Info}";
    }
}
```

Parse the intput into a collection of those objects. This will also allow you to filter better for certain criteria like title, ordernumber and so on

```
public IEnumerable<Item> ParseInput(string[] allLines)
{
    int stepPerItem = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Length - stepPerItem; i += stepPerItem)
    {
        yield return new Item
        {
            OrderNumber = Convert.ToInt32(allLines[i]),
            TimeStampString = allLines[i + 1],
            Info = allLines[i + 2]
        };
    }
}
```

Then in the end you call this method, parse the text into objects and display simply each item. There you can add an additional new line after each entry:

```
List<Item> allItems = ParseInput(allLines.ToArray()).ToList();
foreach (var item in allItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

and your output will look like this:

```
1
00:00:00,000  -->  00:00:03,160
[music]

2
00:00:03,160  -->  00:00:06,620
Thank you for joining me in Arduino step by step 2017,

3
00:00:06,620  -->  00:00:10,900
getting started, in this lecture I will describe

4
00:00:10,900  -->  00:00:15,640
the course so that you know exactly what to expect from it.
```

Comment: This would probably eliminate purposeful dupes, too, won't it? Could it be tweaked to only throw out numeric dupes?

Comment: @Fildor I guess it would. OP should specify the variability of the input a little better.

Comment: the result is almost like what i want, but how can i make before the order number there is empty line like this picture https://i.imgur.com/aIb8qsv.png

Comment: @Joseph you should put a little more thought into parsing of it. You only know the structure and how it can vary. The image is about output. I would advise to create a class that holds all the proper information and create a collection with those objects filled with the values from the file

Comment: @Joseph I added a slightly more object oriented approach to the answer. I also mention the display part. Have a look

Comment: thanks for your answer, it seems your code only work if the text subtitle is one line, if more than one line it will not work 99
00:05:36,460  -->  00:05:36,480
more advanced Arduino topics, technologies and techniques.
You’ll also be well in your journey of learning

Comment: int stepPerItem = 3;

Comment: @Joseph " if more than one line it will not work " did I oversee this in your example that you have posted? or where does this come from?

Comment: yes sometime there are case where subtitle that has more than two line, your code is not working for more than on line, it's statis not dinamis

Comment: @Joseph sorry mate, but if you don't post this possible case, then I cannot anticipate that there are *sometimes* "more than two line". Everything that is still in your head and not in your post is practically still your problem to solve. You gave us a problem description and we gave you solutions based on your description. The solutions are as good and applicable as your description mate

Answer (score 2):

It seems, you want to eliminate dupicate *numbers* and get rid of double *empty lines*:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> RemoveDuplicates(string fileName) {
  HashSet<string> numbers = new HashSet<string>();

  bool isEmpty = false;
  
  foreach (string current in File.ReadLines(fileName).Select(line => line.Trim())) {
    if (current.Any() && current.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9')) // Number
      if (!numbers.Add(current))                                 // Duplicate?
        continue;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(current)) // Empty line
      if (isEmpty)                     // Repeats? 
        continue;
      else
        isEmpty = true;                // Empty line; we are ready to get rid of next one 
    else
      isEmpty = false;

    yield return current;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach (string line in RemoveDuplicates(@"c:\myText.txt"))
  Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Comment: current.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9'), it's work if the number is more than 9, for example 45

Comment: @Joseph: it works for all positive numbers; we can well have subtitle `12` with `12` being duplicated

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `ReadAllLines` method, then removing the empty lines (rather than doing the `\r\n` substitution). Then you can compare the next line with the previous and remove it, if it is the same. Like so:

```
var file = @"nameoffile.srt";
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file).Where(l => l.Trim().Length > 0).ToList();
var people = lines
    .Skip(1)
    .Select((p, index) => p.Equals(lines[index]) ? String.Empty: lines[index]);

foreach (var item in people)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: the result is almost like what i want, but how can i make before the order number there is empty line like this picture i.imgur.com/aIb8qsv.png

Comment: Easy! just remove the last `.Where(l => l.Trim().Length > 0)` and it will preserve these empty lines. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

using your code when you split your line on `\r\n\r\n` then your first `item` looks like `1\r\n\r\n1` so changing your split to look like this:
 `string[] people = lines.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" },                                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`
and using the for each with a `HashSet<int>` like this:

```
    HashSet<int> hlines = new HashSet<int>();
    foreach (var item in people)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(item, out int ordernr))
        {
            if (hlines.Contains(ordernr))
                continue;
            else
            {   
                Console.WriteLine();//adds a line above the order no
                hlines.Add(ordernr);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```

will result in your output only showing 1 order number.

Comment: the result is almost like what i want, but how can i make before the order number there is empty line like this picture https://i.imgur.com/aIb8qsv.png

Comment: In that case I would do something like @Mong Zhu. But if you have to use a foreach loop for some reason you can add a new line when you add the order number to the HashSet. I've updated the code to show this. You will have a blank line at the top of the output though.